# simulate incoming packets on a network interface in linux

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming

If you normally send tcpreplay of a pcap through an interface say eth0 , the packets are outbound, ie will go out through the network card . Is there any way i can make the pcaps inbound so that my system should process it as an inbound packet?

Possible Scenario

I have an application that receives packet from eth0, extract some details from the packet and sends it through eth1. Now the situation is fine if the network is setup and real packets actually flow in to my system. But for testing purposes , i do not have anything connected to my eth0 or eth1 ports , but i still want to create similar kind of traffic from a pcap(probably through a script ) so that i dont have to depend on an external physical network connection for testing the application.

Comment: Do you need your packets to hit the iptables INPUT/FORWARD chains just like the "real" traffic does or is it ok to ignore the firewall? Do you just need the dst mac of the packet match the eth0 ones or do you need that the kernel "think" that the packet was received via eth0, i.e. packet's internal structure pointing to the eth0 as originator?

Comment: I want the kernel "think" that the packet was received via eth0...ie packet's internal structure pointing to the eth0 as originator...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `eth0` with `lo`

1. Run your application which receives packets from `lo` and sends packets to `eth1`
2. Run another program (packet generator) which send packets to `lo`

every packet send to `lo` will be received by `lo` again, so your application will receive packets from your packet generator.

if your `lo` is busy with other packets, you can add more loopback device by kernel argument `max_loop=x`

Comment: +1 This seems to work on my system. That said, `lo` is not an Ethernet interface, so there might be issues at some level. In fact, `tcpreplay` would not work with loopback interfaces for a long time, and even now outputs a warning...

Comment: @user956030, can you give an example how do you do it?

Answer (score 5):

There are several possible solutions:

- *The quick and dirty solution:* Since you have two physical connections, have you considered using a patch cable to connect the two Ethernet ports on your machine? You would then be able to use `libpcap` to send packets out through `eth1` and receive them through `eth0`. Of course, this solution requires physical access to the machine and you would also lose the ability to use those connections normally.
- *The Right solution:* It seems to me that what you are looking for is a way to emulate traffic through a physical network interface. The typical way to do that on Linux (and possibly some other Unix-like systems) is to create a [TAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) virtual interface. Have a look [here](http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/) for a simple tutorial on TUN/TAP interfaces.

  Unfortunately, `tpcreplay` does not appear to support TUN/TAP interfaces yet. You *might* be able to somehow make it work, but I suspect it will be quite awkward.
- *The middle ground:* Use a Linux virtual machine on e.g. [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/). I am not sure on the exact network configuration that is needed, but as far as I can tell this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to send AND receive the packets on the same computer but via particular network card/interface?
The only way that I know of how you can do it is to set up a bounce/echo server.

Comment: OK, that makes it clear that my method (the only one that I know of) is going to be of no use to you. Sorry.

Comment: Did you try iptable to redirect outbound (eth0) traffic to Inbound(eth1) interface?

Comment: @Satish, can you tell me how would you do that? I want to do something like redirecting traffic from one interface to another, like the LAN traffic with a routing rule is going to TAP interface which inturn i want to redirect to ppp interface, how can i do it??